# Is there a command to list all abstract unix sockets currently open?

Tags: linux, command-line, unix-sockets

Is there a command or system call for listing all the abstract unix sockets currently open?

**Update**: It was suggested that I use `netstat -x`, which theoretically works, but does not list the names of the abstract sockets, only those with paths.

```
bash-5.0$ netstat -xeW
Active UNIX domain sockets (w/o servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node Path
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     3959158
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     3961068
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     3965008
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     3967192 /run/spire/writable/agent.sock
```

Comment: Urm, `netstat -x`?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov, See update.

Comment: What about `cat /proc/net/unix`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Abstract sockets

Their path name starts with the NUL characters, making their path length 0. They can use the remaining 107 characters to define a unique identifier, which other programs can use to connect.
they are not represented in the file system.

Most unix come with lsof (list of open files) command. If not you can easily add it.

```
lsof -U

upowerd   1604       root    5u  unix 0xffff88005af5f400      0t0 18631 type=STREAM
colord    1614     colord   10u  unix 0xffff880034d3f400      0t0 18170 type=STREAM
systemd   2009       root   13u  unix 0xffff88005a293000      0t0 21213 /run/user/0/systemd/notify type=DGRAM
systemd   2009       root   14u  unix 0xffff88005a293c00      0t0 21214 /run/user/0/systemd/private type=STREAM
```

On Linux, when showing abstract namespace paths, null bytes are converted to @. Older tool versions may not handle zero bytes properly

```
upstart   1525    lightdm    7u  unix 0xffff880034b99800      0t0 17301 @/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/111/1525 type=STREAM
```

You'll be able to list all the unix domain sockets on your system.

the 'ss' command can also show sockets and abstract sockets. again abstract sockets will be prefixed with @

Good Luck!